# Python: change labels of a plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I want to change the labels of a plot

```
fig=figure(figsize=(7.5,7.5))
labels = [0,0.00001,0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1]
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlim(10^-6,1.1) 
plt.xticks(y, labels)
```

[image]

However I would like to have the labels in the format `10^-5, 10^-4, 10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1, 1` instead of `1e-05, 0.0001, 0,001, 0,01, 0.1, 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this `FormatStrFormatter('%.2e')`

Since you didn't post your whole script I can only show you an example:

If we take this demo from [matplolib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html)

Simply change `majorFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%d')` to what I showed you earlier and you'll see

[image]

You'll simply reformat the major axis to:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2e'))
```